# How to Enable Soap in centos 7

Tags: soap, centos7

I want to enable soap in remote server. I'm using centos 7 and php 5.6.9(php56w). I follow the instructions written in the web but still I can't enable the soap.

I already added in /usr/local/lib/php.ini

```
extension="soap.so"
```

or

```
extension="/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20131226/soap.so"
```

or

```
extension="/usr/lib64/php-zts/modules/soap.so"
```

but still didn't work.

Comments are highly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you need

```
make clean
```

To clean last compilation. Next compile php with:

```
./configure  --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs --with-mcrypt --with-zlib --with-openssl --enable-mbstring --enable-mbregex --with-pdo-pgsql=/usr/local/pgsql --with-pgsql=/usr/local/pgsql --enable-soap --enable-sockets --enable-calendar
```

And finaly:

```
make && make install
```

Answer (score 0):

Php was compiled from binary or installed from repo? If compiled, then you need recompile it with --enable-soap

Comment: thanks for reply. how to recompile? I follow this steps in https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204404004/configure-php-with-soap#4 but did not work.  when I run this coomand  **php -i | grep -i soap** it give a result of
Configure Command =>  './configure'  '--with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs' '--with-mcrypt' '--with-zlib' '--with-openssl' '--enable-mbstring' '--enable-mbregex' '--with-pdo-pgsql=/usr/local/pgsql' '--with-pgsql=/usr/local/pgsql' '--enable-soap=shared' '--enable-sockets' '--enable-calendar' .